# Reorganize hash in specific format

Tags: perl

```
%files_data = {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

              './GetOpt.pm' => {
                          'pid' => {
                                     '56061' => 1,
                                     '56065' => 1
                                   }
                            },
              'file1' => {
                          'pid' => {
                                     '56061' => 2
                                   }
                        },
              'file2' => {
                         'pid' => {
                                    '56065' => 2
                                  }
                       },
              './src/bin/perl' => {
                            'pid' => {
                                       '56061' => 1,
                                       '56065' => 1
                                     }
                          }
                    };

%process_data = (

          '56061' => {
                       'parent' => 'NA',
                       'name' => 'file1'
                     },
          '56069' => {
                       'parent' => '56065',
                       'name' => 'echo Hello_file1'
                     },
          '56062' => {
                       'parent' => '56061',
                       'name' => 'echo Hello_file2'
                     },
          '56065' => {
                       'parent' => '56061',
                       'name' => 'file2'
                     }
        );
```

I would like to iterate through the `$files_data` hash and for each file get the chain of files.
So I'll get the following hash:

```
%hash = (
        'file1' => {
            '/src/bin/perl' => 1,
            'file2' => { 
                '/src/bin/perl' => 1,
                './GetOpt.pm' => 1
            },
            './GetOpt.pm' => 1,
    }
);
```

I need to follow the pid chain up to the main parent ('NA') for each file.

What would be the most efficient way to solve it? I need some guidance on how to implment it.

**EDIT**: Lets take for example `'./GetOpt.pm'` file. it has a pid `56061` so we go to the `%process_data` and see `'file1'` (which is a file). Also we see that the parent of `56061` is `NA` so we stop and get:

```
file1 => ./GetOpt.pm
```

But `./GetOpt.pm` has another pid - `56065` so we go to `56065` and see `file2` (which is a file). Then we go to `56061` which has `file1` (which is s file). so we get:

```
file1 => file2 => ./GetOpt.pm
```

Combine it:

```
file1 => {
    ./GetOpt.pm,
    file2 => ./GetOpt.pm
}
```

I would like to build a process file chain (only with files). the `%files_data` contains valid files and `%process_data` contains the hierarchy of the process we need to follow

Comment: Can you describe how the resulting hash should be constructed from the input data?

Comment: @choroba, please take a look at my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a recursive subroutine that adds a chain of file names into an existing hash. I had to fix your expected structure by prepending `.` to `/src/bin/perl`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %files_data = (
    './GetOpt.pm'    => {pid => {56061 => 1,
                                 56065 => 1}},
    'file1'          => {pid => {56061 => 2}},
    'file2'          => {pid => {56065 => 2}},
    './src/bin/perl' => {pid => {56061 => 1,
                                 56065 => 1}}
);

my %process_data = (
    '56061' => {'parent' => 'NA',
                'name' => 'file1'},
    '56069' => {'parent' => '56065',
                'name' => 'echo Hello_file1'},
    '56062' => {'parent' => '56061',
                'name' => 'echo Hello_file2'},
    '56065' => {'parent' => '56061',
                'name' => 'file2'}
);

my %expected = (
    'file1' => {
        './src/bin/perl' => 1,
        'file2' => {
            './src/bin/perl' => 1,
            './GetOpt.pm' => 1
        },
        './GetOpt.pm' => 1,
    }
);

use Test::More;
use Test::Deep;

sub hashify {
    my ($tree, @chain) = @_;
    my $head = shift @chain;
    $tree->{$head} = @chain ? {} : 1 unless ref $tree->{$head};
    hashify($tree->{$head}, @chain) if @chain;
}

sub add {
    my ($tree, $key) = @_;
    for my $pid (keys %{ $files_data{$key}{pid} }) {
        my @chain = $key;
        while ($pid ne 'NA') {
            my ($parent, $name) = @{ $process_data{$pid} }{qw{ parent name }};
            unshift @chain, $name unless $name eq $chain[0];
            $pid = $parent;
        }
        hashify($tree, @chain);
    }
}

my $result = {};
add($result, $_) for keys %files_data;

cmp_deeply($result, \%expected);
done_testing();
```

Comment: Is it possible to somehow replace `hashify` with a loop? I was trying to switch it by using the `foreach` loop but without any success.

Comment: Why? Recursion can be always replaced by a loop, but you have to provide the bookkeeping to emulate the stack.